# undefined index error - image upload same code is working with another example

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload, undefined

The image upload with php is not working for some reason can somebody here solve the problem?

HTML code:

```
<td>Business Image<br><td>  <input type="file" name="photo">
<td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Setup"></td>
```

MYSQL:

### Table structure for table `markers`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `markers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `days` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `openingHours` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `img` blob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=51
```

The PHP Code

```
     <?php
                    include ("../Connections/Connection.php");



                    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                        $name = $_POST["name"];
                        $type = $_POST["type"];
                        $address = $_POST["address"];
                        $email = $_POST["email"];
                        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
                        $link = $_POST["link"];
                        $lng = $_POST["lng"];
                        $lat = $_POST["lat"];
                        $days = implode(";", $_POST['days']);
                        $openingHours = implode(";", $_POST['openingHours']);
                        $img = time().$_FILES['photo']['name'];
                        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],'../Uploads/'.$img))  die("error");

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO markers (name,  type, address, email, phone, link, lng, lat, days, openingHours, img)
VALUES('$name', '$type', '$address', '$email', '$phone', '$link', '$lng', '$lat', '$days', '$openingHours', '$img')";

                            $query = mysql_query($sql);

                            if (!$query) {
                                die("Error : " . mysql_error());
                            }
                            if (empty($name) || empty($type) || empty($address) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($lng) || empty($lat) || empty($days) || empty($openingHours) || empty($img)) {
                                echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
                                die();  // Note this
                            }
                            echo "<center></center>";
                        }


                        ?>
```

It works perfectly without the upload file button.. but when I add the photo field I got :

Notice: Undefined index: photo in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\BackEnd\ShopSetup.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined index: photo in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\BackEnd\ShopSetup.php on line 57
error

That was long but I couldn't make the explanation shorter

Comment: Try to print out your $_FILES and check photo index is there or not? Also please check @Alen sayings also

Comment: How have you specified your `form` element? It'll need to look something like `<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: @Alan you are so smart! looking at the small details! you solved it

Comment: <form method="POST" action="../BackEnd/ShopSetup.php" name="Setup"> .. I forgot the enctype

Comment: Excellent, though not so smart - I've just done the same thing myself so many times :). I'll post that as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading file data, you need to set the encoding on your `<form>` element to multipart, e.g.:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, it works without enctype when the inputs are not files or images! because it was working with the previous entries!